# Problems looping a method call on PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I've done a small GUI on QtDesigner and I wish to update the text in it every X seconds, as there is a clock included. However, I've ran into multiple problems with the line of thought I chose to go.

So, QTDesigner created `class Ui_MainWindow(object):` with a setup method `def setupUi(self, MainWindow):` (which my entire GUI is built upon) and `def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):` (which is when the text gets written). The defeault code generated by the .ui calls the method ( `self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)`) as the last line of `def setupUi(self, MainWindow):` .

Updating the information of the GUI requires me to loop the writing method, so every X seconds, it rewrites itself.

```
    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda : self.retranslateUi(MainWindow))
    self.timer.start(30000)
```

The code above is what I got into after a few hours of research (discarding the option to use Threads). It, however, simply does not work at all, meaning the method to write never gets called and the GUI is just blank.

It's a big code so I dont think it would be a good idea to post its entirety unless its necessary

Sample:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
     (the UI)
     self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
     self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda : self.retranslateUi(MainWindow))
     self.timer.start(30000)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
     (write things on the labels and text boxes)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.showMaximized()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This sounds like a roundabout way of doing things. Grouping all actions for setting the labels for all the widgets in `retranslateUi` is just how the way QtDesigner does things. This method is normally called only once just after all the widgets are added to the initial ui. When setting up or modifying a .ui manually you would normally set the text for the labels directly.

Comment: I've added a few methods for calling APIs and the clock itself. I feel like I need to be able to call retranslateUI in some sort of a loop for it to update the GUI directly while its running. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @wayzera no, you don't need to call it in amy way, and you shouldn't; consider what would happen if you had a very complex and extended ui: `retranslateUi` would probably have hundreds of different strings (not only labels, but also buttons, tooltips and statustips), what sense should resetting all that have, just because you need to update one single widget? As pointed out, retranslateUi is just what Designer does to group all functions, and is actually fundamental only for localization. Do you understand what its functions do and why? Is localization fundamental for your constant updates?

Comment: Currently my GUI only has labels and `retranslateUI` exclusively writes on those labels. Every single line of code inside it (other than a `MainWindow.setWindowTitle:` is a `setText`  or `setHtml` 

If I'm not supposed to call it again, am I supposed to create another method  with the the exact same content (excluding the lines to set window title) and call it? If so, how am I supposed to call it automatically after the program is already running (since `timeout.connect` is unresponsive

Comment: Made it work. Calling it after the timer.start fixes the issue.

Comment: I'll try to explain one last time. Files generated by pyuic are meant only as "resources", they only serve to *initialize* the ui around existing Qt widget classes. Those files should never be edited: in fact, you should *only* import them (see [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)) and *completely ignore* their contents. If you want to update a label, just call `setText('text')` on that label. If you need localization, read the related documentation, but don't try to reproduce what `retranslateUi` does just because it's called by those files.

Comment: Don't do things just because something or someone does them. Understand **what** those things do and **why**. Copying something without knowing what it does and the reason behind it is the worst way of learning things. Read, study, be patient, do your best to understand. Look for the documentation, search for examples, explanations and tutorials, do experiments, see their results, and learn from the changes and the behavior of the functions you're using. Don't look for the final solution and then just imitate it: try to understand how to get to that solution, how others did it, how and why.